# the navbar with reacte route and darkmode doesnt work together

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, darkmode

I have created a navbar with light and dark mode, everything working well. Now I want to update it to multi-page with `react-router` and with a layout. If I gave to the path name to the url is working well. The problem is the url shows me the page but the navbar doesn't navigate to the url and doesn't toggle the dark/light mode.

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import "./header.css";
import { Link, useMatch, useResolvedPath } from "react-router-dom"

const nav__links = [
  {
    to: "home",
    display: "Home",
  },

  {
    to: "service",
    display: "Service",
  },

  {
    to: "preise",
    display: "Preise",
  },

  {
    to: "kontakt",
    display: "Kontakt",
  },
];

const Header = ({ theme, toggleTheme }) => {
  const headerRef = useRef(null);

  const menuRef = useRef(null);

  const headerFunc = () => {
    if (
      document.body.scrollTop > 80 ||
      document.documentElement.scrollTop > 80
    ) {
      headerRef.current.classList.add("header__shrink");
    } else {
      headerRef.current.classList.remove("header__shrink");
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("scroll", headerFunc);

    return () => window.removeEventListener("scroll", headerFunc);
  }, []);

  const handleClick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const targetAttr = e.target.getAttribute("to");

    const location = document.querySelector(targetAttr).offsetTop;

    window.scrollTo({
      left: 0,
      top: location - 80,
    });
  };

  const toggleMenu = () => menuRef.current.classList.toggle("menu__active");

  function CustomLink({ to, children, ...props }) {
    const resolvedPath = useResolvedPath(to)
    const isActive = useMatch({ path: resolvedPath.pathname, end: true })
  
    return (
      <li className={isActive ? "active" : ""}>
        <Link to={to} {...props}>
          {children}
        </Link>
      </li>
    );
  };

  return (
    <header className="header" ref={headerRef}>
      <div className="container">
        <div className="nav__wrapper">
          <div className="logo" to="home">
              <Link to="home"><h2>Q-Tech</h2></Link>
          </div>

          {/* ========= navigation ============= */}
          <div className="navigation" ref={menuRef} onClick={toggleMenu}>
            <ul className="menu">
              {nav__links.map((item, index) => (
                <li className="menu__item" key={index}>
                  <CustomLink
                    to={item.to}
                    onClick={handleClick}
                    className="menu__link"
                  >
                    {item.display}
                  </CustomLink>
                </li>
              ))}
            </ul>
          </div>

          {/* ============ light mode ============= */}
          <div className="light__mode">
            <span onClick={toggleTheme}>
              {theme === "light-theme" ? (
                <span>
                  <i class="ri-moon-line"></i>Dark
                </span>
              ) : (
                <span>
                  <i class="ri-sun-line"></i> Light
                </span>
              )}
            </span>
          </div>
          <span className="mobile__menu" onClick={toggleMenu}>
            <i class="ri-menu-line"></i>
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>
  );
};

export default Header;
```

Comment: Which ***specific*** issue do you want help with in this post, the navigation issue or the dark/light mode issue? This post needs more focus.

Comment: You probably also don't want to nest `li` elements inside another `li` element. Try using the `NavLink` component which applies an `"active"` classname by default.

Answer (score 0):

**Why navigation is not working?**

Look at the navigation link definition - `CustomLink`:

```
<CustomLink
  onClick={handleClick} // <--
   ...
>
```

You have an `onClick` handler on the link. Inside this event handler you call `e.preventDefault()`, which prevents the navigaton behaviour.

**Why toggle light/dark theme it not working?**

The toggle button here looks fine. So it is probably a problem in the code outside `Header` component. Try to debug `toggleTheme` functionality.